# Manifest. Error executing binary in release version

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005, manifest

I'm developing a binary file in windows XP with Visual Studio 2005. I've generated debug and release versions of my application and on my machine all goes fine. But, when I try to run the application on another machine, the debug version runs fine (I think because I have the same Visual Studio on both machines), but the release version is having problems executing (i have the same version of redistributables). 
Reading here in Stackoverflow, I've set the embedded manifest to *no*, and when I generate my application, I can see my release manifest and its content is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

  <dependency>

    <dependentAssembly>

      <assemblyIdentity type="win32"
       name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" 
       version="8.0.50727.762" 
       processorArchitecture="x86" 
       publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
      </assemblyIdentity>

    </dependentAssembly>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <dependentAssembly>

      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" 
       name="Microsoft.VC80.MFC" 
       version="8.0.50727.762" 
       processorArchitecture="x86" 
       publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
      </assemblyIdentity>

    </dependentAssembly>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <dependentAssembly>

      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" 
       name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" 
       version="8.0.50727.4053" 
       processorArchitecture="x86" 
       publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
      </assemblyIdentity>

    </dependentAssembly>

  </dependency>

</assembly>
```

If I remove the last entry, 8.0.50727.4053 in the manifest of the destination machine, I can run the application successfully but, why this entry is added to the manifest? How can I remove it?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Manifests are the Microsoft solution to their DLL hell. There is one (libname, version) entry for every library your program use, so that Windows can load the correct version.

About the removal:

You can try if your VS version has the ability to link the MFC and CRT libraries statically into the executable. Then these items should disappear from the manifest.

If you can't statically link and you have full control about your runtime environment, you can simply ship without the .manifest file. When you can't control your runitme environment, it is better to create an installer for your application, which bundles the needed libraries.

Comment: yes, but what can I do to remove this 8.0.50727.4053 entry of the manifest? and why my app runs without this entry???

Answer (score 0):

When you build a project in VS2005, using the DLL Runtime, the compiler automatically includes information that is used to add dependentAssembly entries to the final manifest.

What is going on here then is probably caused by you including a static library project, built with VS2005 RTM, and now you are trying to build a project using VS2005 SP1.

Your solutions are:

- Rebuild the static libraries in your project with the most recent VS2005, so all dependentAssemblies point to the same, latest, version.
- Rebuild your EXE only, with options to force it to reference the RTM runtime. Instructions are [here](http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/avoiding-problems-with-vc2005-sp1-security-update-kb971090/)
- Disable the automatic manifests entirely, and simply ship a hand crafted one with only a single dependentAssembly CRT reference, being your preferred CRT version.